# how to calculate average when some rows does not exist?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, olap

Please help to create average when some values are NULL

fact table:

[image]

cube:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Score]} * [Date].[Month].allmembers ON COLUMNS
,{[Name].[name].allmembers} ON ROWS
FROM Test
```

[image]

problem:

when I calculate average, NULL values are excluded. I tried COALESCEEMPTY(), but did not manage to calculate average correctly anyway. Average for months where Score=0 is not correct. Heres the code:

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[DateCount] AS DISTINCTCOUNT([Data].[date].[date])
MEMBER [Measures].[ScoreX] AS COALESCEEMPTY([Measures].[Score],0)
MEMBER [Measures].[DateCountX] AS COALESCEEMPTY([Measures].[DateCount],0)
MEMBER [Measures].[AvgScore] AS IIF([Measures].[DateCountX]=0,0,[Measures].[ScoreX]/[Measures].[DateCountX])
 SELECT NON EMPTY {[Measures].[AvgScore]} * [Date].[Month].allmembers ON COLUMNS
 ,{[Name].[name].allmembers} ON ROWS
 FROM Test
```

[image]

Please help find the solution.

Comment: You need to use COALESCE_EMPTY to replace the empty cells with zeros.

Comment: I added COALESCEEMPTY, now the table has no empty cells, but 0's instead. Nevertheless the "Total Score" is the same. How could I make it calculate correct values ?

Comment: How are you calculating [Data Count]?   I don't see it in your fact table.   It seems to me you're after:   (Score1 + Score2)/2 and I don't know how [Data Count] enters into it.

Comment: I updated the question with details how I get [Data Count]

Comment: Ok, then you can't divide by DataCount, or you will still be dividing by one when there is no row in the fact table for one of the months.   You need to divide by the number of months you are returning data for.

Comment: that makes sense. Please could you help write correct MDX ?

Comment: Can you post your complete current MDX so I can see how you are choosing which months to show, and where the names come from?

Comment: Actually I have no MDX at all, just single "CREATE MEMBER" statement which is already in the question. I do query in excel and filter by month there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92981/discussion-between-pirmas-naujas-and-tab-alleman).

Comment: Oh, I'm not an Excel Powerpivot expert.   Hopefully somebody else can pick up the thread from here.

Comment: well I am still stuck with calculating average and creating calculated member, not with using excel.

Comment: Problem is, what you want, to the best of my knowledge, requires interaction between measures and dimensions (Time and Name).   I wouldn't approach this purely with calculated measures from the fact table.   If Excel allows you to do that somehow, I have no idea how.   But for a pure MDX solution, I would need to use your dimensions, which aren't described in your question.

Comment: please check the question, I updated with little more info about my current query for the cube. Maybe this will help you to understand it. thanks again for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the final solution was this:

```
WITH

MEMBER Measures.[AvgScore] AS
Avg(
Descendants(
[Data].[Date].CurrentMember,
[Data].[Date].[Date]
),
coalesceempty(Measures.[Score],0)
)

 SELECT NON EMPTY {[Measures].[AvgScore]} * [Date].[Month].allmembers ON COLUMNS
 ,{[Name].[name].allmembers} ON ROWS

FROM Test
```

Comment: (upped) thanks for posting - I've not used `coalesceempty` before.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like the following:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[Score X] AS
  IIF(
    [Measures].[Data Count]=0
    ,0
    ,[Measures].[Data Count]
  )
MEMBER [Measures].[Data Count X] AS
  COUNT(
    [name].[name].CURRENTMEMBER
    *[Measures].[Score X]
  )
MEMBER [Measures].[Avg Score] AS
  DIVIDE(
    [Measures].[Score]
   ,[Measures].[Data Count X]
  )
...
...
```

As Tab mentioned, you could use the function `COALESCEEMPTY` for the first calculated member above:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[Score X] AS
  COALESCEEMPTY(
    [Measures].[Data Count]
    ,0)
MEMBER [Measures].[Data Count X] AS
  COUNT(
    [name].[name].CURRENTMEMBER
    *[Measures].[Score X]
  )
MEMBER [Measures].[Avg Score] AS
  DIVIDE(
    [Measures].[Score]
   ,[Measures].[Data Count X]
  )
...
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did not understand the variables you use. Is there some mistype in second MEMBER statement ? [Data Count] is used in first statement to add zeros and create [Score X]. In second statement [Data Count] is created and [Score X] is used. Please check is this is correct ?

Comment: - true - let me add a couple more "X"

Comment: Please explain second statement. When I implement it I get #VALUE! all over

Comment: Does the DIVIDE() function do something to avoid division by zero?   I've never used it.

Comment: @TabAlleman there is another argument you can use + it is recent so may be quicker than `/` operator

Comment: What do you mean by `second statement` - could you please add your complete script to the original question

Comment: What is the logic behind below calculated member. Why multiply ? This one is not working for me: MEMBER [Measures].[Data Count X] AS
  COUNT(
    [name].[name].CURRENTMEMBER
    *[Measures].[Score X]
  )

Comment: This is an alternative: `COUNT(NonEmpty(
    [name].[name].CURRENTMEMBER
    ,[Measures].[Score X]
  ))`

Comment: @whytheq could you please check updated question. I hope this will be more helpful to find solution to create "average" calculated measure

Answer (score 0):

Your fact table needs to represent 0's for each month with missing names.  You could do this with a common-table-expression.

```
declare @facttable table(name varchar(10),date datetime,score int);

insert into @facttable(name,date,score)
values
    ('a1','2015/01/01',15),
    ('a2','2015/01/01',30),
    ('a3','2015/01/01',26),
    ('a1','2015/02/01',20),
    ('a3','2015/02/01',14),
    ('a4','2015/02/01',45),
    ('a5','2015/02/01',3)



;

with fact_cte as(

    select
        tDistinctNames.DistinctName AS Name,
        tDistinctDates.DistinctDate AS Date,
        ISNULL(t.Score,0) AS Score

    from 
        (select distinct name as DistinctName from @facttable) tDistinctNames
            cross join
        (select distinct date as DistinctDate from @facttable) tDistinctDates

            left outer join @facttable t on 
                t.name = tDistinctNames.DistinctName AND
                t.date = tDistinctDates.DistinctDate

)
select *
from fact_cte
```

The result would be this:

```
Name    Date    Score
a1  2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 15
a2  2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 30
a3  2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 26
a4  2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 0
a5  2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 0
a1  2015-02-01 00:00:00.000 20
a2  2015-02-01 00:00:00.000 0
a3  2015-02-01 00:00:00.000 14
a4  2015-02-01 00:00:00.000 45
a5  2015-02-01 00:00:00.000 3
```

Comment: This is an option but not very scalable. I would imagine finding a solution within analysis services via mdx is a better route to follow.

Comment: Pretty sure OP is looking for an MDX solution.